# Generate serializable classes from entity framework classes?

Tags: c#, web-services, blackberry, code-generation

Here's my problem:

I am creating a Blackberry application that access's my data via a web service.
The web service is using entity framework which was created for my web application.

I use the SUN wireless toolkit stub generator to create the code and classes to access the web service from the Blackberry application. The stub generator does not like dates and fields that return collections so I usally have to create new classes manually that deal with this.

Idea:

I want to be able to generate these classes automatically from my entity framework model?

What is the best way to do this?

I would like to make this generic. Something similar to the [POCO generator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/01/25/walkthrough-poco-template-for-the-entity-framework.aspx) would be ideal

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I know about Entity Framework, it has some XML-based schema description. You can write relatively simple XSLT transformation, which will transform this XML into a set of classes suitable for transmitting over the wire.